# CSV file row and column iteration

Tags: python, csv, row, traceback

I'm having trouble trying to return row 1 of a csv file, which basically contains a string of data: [0, 300, 30, 521, 53, 462, 642]. Basically I'm trying to delete the first column, and then iterate through the first row [300, 30, 521, 53, 462, 642] and append the minimum value (30) into a list called "b". Then repeat that with the second row and second column and so on. However, I get an error and I'm not sure what it means. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "travelsales.py", line 25, in <module>
    nearest(0);
  File "travelsales.py", line 17, in nearest
    for i in reader.next():
StopIteration
```

Source code:

```
import time
import csv
from itertools import islice

b = list();
reader = csv.reader(open('distance.csv','rU'), delimiter = ' ');
def delete(column):
    for i in reader:
        del i[column];

def nearest(row):
    a = list();
    list(islice(reader, row));
    for i in reader.next():
        a.append(int(i));
    print a;
    b.append(min(a));
    del a[:];
    print b;

delete(0);
nearest(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You exhaust your `reader` in delete - it's similar to reading to the end of a file. This approach is overcomplicated. To meet the revised goal of calculating the min of each row, ignoring the nth column in each nth row, I would do this:

```
b = []
for rownum, line in enumerate(reader):
    b.append(min(int(x) for x in line[:rownum] + line[rownum + 1:])
```

Since each `line` list is already created, I think slicing directly is faster than `itertools.islice`. List addition vs. `itertools.chain` I'm not so sure about.

```
min(min(int(x) for x in line[:rownum]), min(int(x) for x in line[rownum + 1:]))
```

might also be worth testing.

Also, Python doesn't use semicolons.

Comment: Sorry, but I probably should've mentioned that I wanted to include more than one row. For example, I have 4 rows, I want to delete the first column of the first row, then find the min, delete the second column of the second row, find the min out of the remaining, then delete the third column of the third row and append.

Comment: Are you always ignoring the nth column when finding the min in the nth row?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do that, but also I want the column to remain deleted so that I can reference the minimum values in the nth row with the remaining columns

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

def read_csv(fname, **kwargs):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as inf:
        in_csv = csv.reader(inf, **kwargs)
        return list(in_csv)

def nearest(row):
    return min(int(i) for i in islice(row, 1, None))

def main():
    data = read_csv('distance.csv', delimiter=' ')
    b = [nearest(row) for row in data]

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```